# No Sound even after fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pavucontrol

I have done everything that I could get off Google to correct the sound problem but none of them is working. My last install of Ubuntu had the sound working, but this one, I don't know why it is not. Pulseaudio/pavucontrol/driver manager/ unmuting alsamixer/ unmuting sound settings/ taking out the jack and plugging it again/ sound card problem  -- all these possibilities I've already eliminated.

I'm tired and frustrated. Please help, my AlsaInfo:

http://pastebin.com/sDCs9brZ

Comment: Which of the sound cards are you trying to use? How did you configure that card?

Comment: can you show the output please `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 audio`

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish That information is already in the alsoinfo output.

Comment: from that info I can't where it says `kernel driver in use:` or nun in use. Can you here `drums` sound at login? is `alsamixer` in terminal specifies the exact card that is currently in use?

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish I'm afraid, I can't hear those drums sound. The alsamixer specifies the two sound cards and I have unmuted both the cards.

Comment: try suggested answer by **123456**, in addtion to his command if it's still no sound try `sudo alsa force-reload` and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Install Sound card drivers and needed Alsa packages :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-base-udeb alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

Comment: The alsainfo output shows that the drivers are already installed.

Comment: @CL Certain packages could have left.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils-udeb
E: Unable to locate package alsa-utils-udeb  I am getting these two lines as reply after the installation starts in the terminal, I guess that means they're not installed. What to do?

Comment: I edited the answer. try now.

Comment: Ok! It's working now! Thanks user224082

Answer (score 0):

- From your alsa info, you have a emu10k1x card in addition to your internal sound card which is the second one: remove the emu10k1x  or select internal sound card when setting volumes, mutings (press F6 in alsamixer or scroll down in Pulseaudio volume control)